# Convert date to YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ format in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, iso8601, to-char

I want to convert the date format to `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSXXXZ` (ISO 8601).

Getting `2021-02-10T04:02:55.55SXXXZ` and it's wrong. I need it as `2021-02-10T04:02:55.55S000000Z`.

```
select to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSXXXZ')
```

Comment: The `55S`  (note the digit `5`) seems wrong. Did you mean `SSS`

Comment: I think you are looking for `select to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.USZ');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ISO 8601 date format you can use below query:

```
select to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')
```

**Output:**
"2021-02-10T12:09:17Z"

Is it your desired format?

Comment: 2021-02-05T00:00:00.000000Z this is a sample. I need the output in this format.

Comment: Is 2021-02-10T12:09:17Z ok? or you want 2021-02-10T12:09:17000Z?